# Extension Method Help

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an extension method where I happen to need the field name that the extension method is needed within the extension method. I can not figure out how to do this.

### My code:

---

#### Extension method:

```
public static Validate Demand<T>(this T parameter)
{
    string name = ...
    var field = GetField(parameter);
    return Validation.CreateValidation(parameter, field, name);
}
```

#### Use case:

```
void SomeMethod(T someParameter)
{
   someParameter.Demand();
}
```

I want `name` to hold `someParameter`.

Comment: It is not possible to do this. What are you really trying to do? There could be another/better way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It would be nice in a few cases, particularly for argument checking, but it's just not possible. As an example of where it would be handy, I have this method:

```
internal static void ThrowIfNull<T>(this T argument, string name)
    where T : class
{
    if (argument == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(name);
    }
}
```

which I have to call with:

```
foo.ThrowIfNull("foo");
```

It's better than nothing, but it would be nice not to have to supply the "foo" bit. Unfortunately, there's just no way of doing it. You could probably write a post-build IL rewriter which determined how the method was called and rebuilt it from that, but that's rather more work than the benefit, I suspect :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get what I think you're asking for:

```
static class Argument
{
    public static void NotNull(Expression<Func<Func<object>>> arg)
    {
        if (arg.Compile()()() == null)
        {
            var body1 = (Expression<Func<object>>)arg.Body;
            var body2 = (MemberExpression)body1.Body;
            throw new ArgumentNullException(body2.Member.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
void F(string foo)
{
    Argument.NotNull(() => () => foo);
```

The great thing about this is that renaming `foo` in the IDE will get all the references.  (If you have `foo` in a string, it will get missed.)

If you use this in a tight loop, it may cause performance problems, because it calls `.Compile()()` each time.  You can optimize for performance by adding this overload:

```
    public static void NotNull(object value, Expression<Func<Func<object>>> arg)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var body1 = (Expression<Func<object>>)arg.Body;
            var body2 = (MemberExpression)body1.Body;
            throw new ArgumentNullException(body2.Member.Name);
        }
    }
```

Which is used like this:

```
Argument.NotNull(foo, () => () => foo);
```

It still gets renames correct, and it saves that call on each iteration.

What I would recommend is using the first version when you write your code, then run it under a profiler, and switch to the second version in the cases that matter.

Comment: It does not appear that this will work for extension methods where atttempting to get the type of "this".